# Is there a possibility that a rendered page state be different in phantomjs and chrome

Tags: testing, phantomjs, automated-tests, capybara

I have a webpage which PhantomJS is rendering differently than Chrome. 
Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible depending on what features the page is using.  PhantonJS 2.1.1 uses Qt 5.5 which is equivalent to a browser from at best 2-3 years ago while Chrome is evergreen.